# Determine target URL within login page using Forms authentication with WebLogic

Tags: java, jsp, forms-authentication, weblogic

I have an application running under WebLogic that is using standard forms authentication.  The login page is a JSP that presents the login form that will post to j_security_check.  So as you would expect, when a user tries to access a page but is not yet authenticated, they will be redirected to the login.jsp.

My question is, how can I determine the page that the user was attempting to hit before WebLogic redirected them to the login page?  I wish to use this to change the content of the login page depending on the user's destination.  I'm not seeing anything in the request ojbect that would tell me this.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We concluded there was no way to find out the target URL from the login page.  I woudln't mind being proven wrong. :)

In the meantime, the solution was to deploy the content in second WAR with it's own login page providing the alternate content.  Lots of overhead for what should be a simple problem to solve.

Comment: I've just tried BaluSc's solution on Weblogic 10.3 today and can confirm `${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}` **works**.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
weblogic.servlet.security.ServletAuthentication.getTargetURLForFormAuthentication(request.getSession())
```

This is a public static method and returns a String.

I've tested and it works for me.

Comment: Normally, the requested url is stored in an attribute in request scope named `'javax.servlet.forward.request_uri'` which is defined in `RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI` constant. However, weblogic does not add it to request attributes. I thought adding this comment makes it easier for others to reach this answer. I hope they will find it sooner than me :)